# measure inequality involving decimal expansion

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, decimal-expansion

For $x\in [0,1), \ \ x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_nx}{10^n}$ where $a_i$ is a digit in 0,1,...,9, define $I(a_1, \cdots ,a_n)$ be all $y\in  [0,1)$ such that the decimal expansion of $y$ has first $n$ digit equal to $a_1, \cdots ,a_n$, respectively. For subset $A\subset [0,1)$, let $N_n(A)=\text{card }\left\{ I(a_1, \cdots, a_n)|I(a_1, \cdots, a_n)\cap A\neq \emptyset \right\}$.

Prove that there exists a Borel set $A\subset [0,1)$,
$$m(A)< \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{N_n(A)}{10^n}$$
where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

I have proved that $m(A)\le \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{N_n(A)}{10^n}$ for all Borel set $A$, but can't find a case this inequality is strict. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can find $A$ so that $m(A)=0$, but $N_n(A)=10^n$ for all $n$. Can you think of a measure zero set which intersects every set of the form $I(a_1,\dots,a_n)$?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Does $\mathbb{Q}$ help here?

Comment: Yep! That's the trick!